# Reduce loop overhead when displaying images inside a loop

Tags: image, matlab, loops, matlab-figure

I'm triggering the video in a loop, make use of its data, and preview what's happening using `imshow`. The external camera has 30 fps, however when using `imshow` in the loop, it substantially reduced the frame rate to around 5-7 fps. Is there a workaround for this? Below is the snippet:

```
Vid = videoinput('some_cam',1);
triggerconfig(Vid, 'manual');
Vid.FramesPerTrigger = 1;
Vid.TriggerRepeat = inf;
viewer = vision.DeployableVideoPlayer();

start(Vid);
himg = figure;
while ishandle(himg)
    trigger(Vid);
    [image, timeStamp] = getdata(Vid);
    imshow(image); %This line significantly reduce the performance
    %Do something with the images...This part is important and would need as many frame rate as possible
end
```

So I was thinking, what if I send `imshow` to run on another thread? But in this case, I can't figure how to do it since I need to access the `image`. Preview or any other command wouldn't work in my case since I'll have to do some alteration on the `image` beforehand.

Comment: Why are you showing the image? Graphics are generally unnecessary and they tend to show things down

Comment: Since I'm dealing with image tracking, I need to allow user see what's tracking, so I can't escape that part unfortunately.

Comment: Make a video, don't display to screen

Comment: But then, I wouldn't be able to show it in almost 'real-time'

Comment: How big is the image?

Comment: It's a `640x480` resolution image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to speed up animated graphics in MATLAB is to not use functions such as `imshow` or `plot`, which clear the axes, create new graphics objects, tweak axes properties, etc. etc. These functions do a lot of work behind the scenes that is not necessary when animating something on screen.

Instead, modify the existing graphics object:

```matlab
start(Vid);
hfig = figure;
trigger(Vid);
[image, timeStamp] = getdata(Vid);
himg = imshow(image);
while ishandle(hfig)
    trigger(Vid);
    [image, timeStamp] = getdata(Vid);
    himg.CData = image; % update the existing graphics object
    %...
end
```

For very old versions of MATLAB, update the graphics object using `set(himg,'CData',image)`.

You might need to add a `drawnow` inside the loop to see the image change.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you use `imshow`, your program will run slowly. One thing that may help speed things up is to show a subset of the data. For example, you can shrink by a factor of 10 in each direction. While the plotting overhead will remain largely the same, `imshow` will have 100 times less data to display:

```
imshow(image(1:10:end, 1:10:end))
```

If the image is color, add a `:` index along the color dimension.

If you plot an overlay of any kind, remember to decide all coordinates by 10 to compensate for the reduced image size.

But in the end, you can't both have the cake and eat it: either you display graphics and accept the overhead, or you don't.